# How to copy or store the contents of inputstream in to byte array?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I am using Apache Commons FileUpload library for uploading files. I want to copy the contents of the InputStream into a single byte array. How could I do that?

```
try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(
            new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input
            // type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldvalue = item.getString();
            out.println("returned");
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            InputStream input = item.getInputStream();
            if (fieldname.equals("file")) {
                // please help me here.
                byte[] allbyte = ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`IOUtils.toByteArray()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) utility method from the [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

InputStream input;
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
```

It gives you a one-liner. In general, try to find an existing library that does what you want, and the [Apache commons libraries](http://commons.apache.org/) have loads of handy methods.

Comment: It should be noted that like the JDK version, the Apache Commons `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` allocates a new array, and copies the bytes into it. In other words, you don't just get a reference to the array used to collect the data in the first place. This could be relevant if you're dealing with quite large files and the cost of double copying the bytes becomes high.

Comment: If we have an `InputStream` (of an image) and want to perform some methods on it (without saving it on the server), is it better to write it to a byte array and pass it to methods rather than passing it around as an `InputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int b = input.read();
while (b != -1) {
    out.write(b);
    b = input.read();
}
allbyte = out.toByteArray();
```

Comment: It should be noted that `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` allocates a new array, and copies the bytes into it. In other words, you don't just get a reference to the array used to collect the data in the first place.  This could be relevant if you're dealing with quite large files and the cost of double copying the bytes becomes high.

Answer (score -1):

Use the DataInputStream. It has a readFully() method which reads all the bytes.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
byte[] allBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
dis.readFully(allBytes);
```

For details, see

[InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29%20)

[DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: I'm not sure that you can rely on `inputStream.available()` to give you a true representation of the size of the upload data.  Available simply returns *"an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next caller of a method for this input stream."*

Comment: @GregKopff inputStream.available() returns the number of bytes that can be read in the program. It is not a problem because allocating excess length has no use as we can read only some of it and the other will be null which will only be a waste of memory